# Objective-C: Getters should not be used for side effects compiler warning

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsarray, notation

Can someone clarify what is happening here. I got an class called: brainModel and it again has an NSArray called: operandStack. I am simply accessing the array sending it the message "removeAllObjects"

```
self.brainModel.operandStack.removeAllObjects;
```

but using dot notation it gives me an warning "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects" What exactly does this mean?

using nested bracket syntax like this gives no warning:

```
 [[[self brainModel]operandStack]removeAllObjects];
```

both works btw... does it have anythig to do with wrong use of dot notation? or is it considered good practice to use dot notation when messaging objects like this - sending it arguments like "removeAllObjects".

Comment: It's probably seeing that `removeAllObjects` has a return type of `void` so you are obviously not using it as a getter

Comment: @Paul.s not at all, see my answer soon.

Answer (score 5):

`removeAllObjects` is not a property; it's a method.

Using property-access notation works because properties are usually accessed using a method of the same name. However, it is expected that getting a property's value will not change the object which contains the object (or make any other changes), which is not the case with `removeAllObjects`. These are the "side effects" that the compiler is referring to.

Probably, you would want to perform this call instead:

```
[self.brainModel.operandStack removeAllObjects];
```

This gets the `brainModel` property of `self`, then the `operandStack` property of `self.brainModel`, then calls `removeAllObjects` on it.

Answer (score 1):

removeAllObjects is a method. You cannot access methods through dot notation; only properties.

Comment: You can, but should you?  It's kind of a question of morality and religion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare each and every method as a property - especially not if they are modifying the object. Getters should be viewed as accessors to a property (without exposing the backing ivar directly). Methods that are 'actions', to say, are to be declared as such (i. e. declared without the `@property` keyword and called using brackets instead of the dot notation).

Comment: That doesn't explain how my suggestion was wrong? I can legitimately declare a method with a return value and use it with dot notation. Check out `- (NSUInteger)count;` in `NSArray` it's not declared as `@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSUInteger count` but many people use it either way with no issues. Although your answer explains the philosophy of using properties I don't think it explains the compiler moaning.

Comment: @Paul.s it does, it just seems you don't understand that **it is not a syntax error** that a compiler complains about, it's exactly the philosophy behind the syntax.

Comment: Agreed it is the philosophy that matters, but I was simply stating that the compiler must be working on the method signature having a `void` return, as how else would it know that it has side effects - keeping in mind I can legitimately add side effects if my method signature actually returns something.